# How can I bind different property types with Bond framework?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label (string) and my object has a property with NSNumber.

How can I bind different property types with Two Way Binding (bidirectional bind)?

EX:

The framework bond: https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond

```
protocol NewTransactionViewModelProtocol
{
    var Price: Observable<NSNumber?>;
}

class NewTransactionView: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var PriceLabel: UILabel!

    var viewModel: NewTransactionViewModelProtocol! 
    {
        didSet 
        {
            viewModel.Price.bidirectionalBindTo(self.PriceLabel.bnd_text); //WRONG
        }
    }
}

PS: PriceLabel.bnd_text : Observable<NSString?>
```

Comment: 1. What is the "Bound framework"?

Comment: 2. Do you mean "type properties"?

Comment: 3. Can you post some pseudo code showing what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've improved my question with links and specific source. 

I want a input text (for example), and typing digits. The type of text is "string" but my binding is NSNumber. How to "convert" the types?

Answer (score 0):

To convert any objects of compatible type A to B, simply do the following:

```
A(B)
```

In your example, what you want to do is:

```
viewModel.Price.bidirectionalBindTo(NSNumber(self.PriceLabel.bnd_text));
```

Comment: Obviously, it doesn't work. Do you know what data binding is and how we can do it with swift?

Comment: @NunoMorais Can't you just use `PriceLabel` when you need it?